# How to load a imported function after another one in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I've the `items.js` file that add the items in the page, the `navigation.js` that detect the click on the items and the `main.js` that load both files.

The problem is that since the items are loaded dynamic, the `navigation.js` must be loaded after the `items.js`.

I've solved this by adding a `setTimeout` to the `navigation.js` import.

My doubt is: there's a better way to do that without the `setTimeout`?

main.js

```
import items from './_items.js';
import navigation from './_navigation.js';

items();

setTimeout(() => {
    navigation();
}, 1000);
```

items.js

```
export default function () {
    fetch('files/items.json').then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
    }).then(function(data) {
        let body = '';
    
        data.map(function(item) {
            body += `<a href="#" class="link">${item.name}</a>`;
        });

        let div = document.getElementById('items');
        div.innerHTML = body;
    });
}
```

navigation.js

```
export default function () {
    const links = document.querySelectorAll('.link');

    links.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', event => {
        event.preventDefault();

        console.log('Click!');
    }));
}
```

Comment: It does not matter which order the functions are _loaded_ or _imported_ in. You need to `await` the `fetch` call. Since `items` doesn’t return anything, the `Promise` returned by `fetch` is unreachable. Just return `fetch`, then do `await items(); navigation();`.

Comment: It worked! Thanks @SebastianSimon. I had tried to use await but I forgot to return the fetch.